# Actionscript 3.0 Best Option for Subclassing Vector Class (Flash Player 10)

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, actionscript, vector

I would like to take advantage of all the goodness of the newer Vector class for FP10, but it seems it is marked as final.

I am doing some intensive mathematical processing in Actionscript, and repeatedly process arrays of Numbers. I have previously been using my own subclass of Array(I call it `NumericArray`), with added functions such as sum(), mean(), add(), multiply(), etc.  This works very well and allows for some clean OO code.  However, I am finding through profiling that about 95% of my processing time occurs in the functions of these objects.  I need more performance out of these arrays.

I want to use a Vector, as it provides some performance enhancements.  I want to specifically use a `Vector.<Number>`.  Unfortunately, I cannot subclass Vector as it is marked final.

What is the best and cleanest way to imitate what I was previously doing with a subclass of Array, to a `Vector.<Number>`?

I have thought about passing around `Vector.<Number>` variables instead of my custom class and just using utility functions to manipulate, but this is not good OO design and will be a pain to use, not to mention ugly.

Comment: FYI, the compilers (mxmlc and compc) do not support writing the definition of generic (.<>) classes, so it wouldn't be possible to subclass Vector even if it wasn't marked final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If adding your additional functionality doesn't require access to protected properties/methods of Vector, you could create a wrapper class for the Vector. Something along these lines?

```
import flash.utils.Proxy;
import flash.utils.flash_proxy;

use namespace flash_proxy;

public class NumericVector extends Proxy
{
     private var vector:Vector.<Number>;

     public function NumericVector(vector:Vector.<Number> = null)
     {
          if(vector == null)
          {
              this.vector = new Vector.<Number>();
          }
          else
          {
              this.vector = vector;
          }
     }

     override flash_proxy function nextName(index:int):String 
     {
         return vector[index - 1].toString();
     }

     override flash_proxy function nextNameIndex(index:int):int
     {
         // implementation
     }

     public function sum():Number
     {
         // do whatever you intend to do
     }

     ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, composition is the other option, it's limitation is that I cannot treat a NumericVector like a regular vector, for example, iteration, or accessing using the indices, like `myVec[0]`.  I will have to come up with some clunky functions to do things like `myVec.set(0, newVal)` instead of `myVec[0] = newVal;` or `myVec.get(0)` instead of `myVec[0]`.

Comment: You can in fact implement this behavior by having the NumericVector extend AS3's Proxy class. I can't say how this will impact speed though...

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of the Proxy class, I'll look into it.  I'm not so concerned about the speed of adding/modifying items in the NumericVector class.  I am concerned with the speed of all the auxiliary functions that require many iterations, and these will be done straight on the Vector within the class.

Comment: Hey its not so hard. Just mark the vector variable `public` and then you can `myVec.vector[0] = newVal;` .. easy isn't it?!

Answer (score 1):

A way to sidestep this issue might be to use the [as3ds](http://code.google.com/p/as3ds/) (short for actionscript 3 data structures). Whether they can be faster than using Vector, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

How come on this page
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/Vector.html

it says:
"Note: To override this method in a subclass of Vector, use ...args for the parameters, as this example shows:"

??

doesn't that imply that you can subclass a Vector?

James